# Get number of comments per page

Tags: comments

I am trying to grab number of comments to display per page. So far unsuccessful, looking for something similar to this `$wp_query->max_num_pages;` Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From quick look at core that would probably be `get_option('comments_per_page')`.

However WP functions just use this internally, why not just let them take care of it? You are not describing *why* do you need to handle this directly.

Comment: I'm using paginate_comments_links() function and I want to add disabled Next link when user hits last page of comments. To do that I need number of total comments pages and by getting number of comments per page I will be able to work out total number of comments pages.